# Fatal error on WordPress login tests! Duplicator Plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I've currently run into an issue while trying to migrate one of my wordpress websites. I have run into an issue that says

`SCRIPT FILE TEST: /home/uarbnvd4dt71/public_html/testingsite.wordpresssite.ca//wp-login.php

E_COMPILE_ERROR Declaration of Automattic\WooCommerce\Vendor\League\Container\Container::get($id, bool $new = false) must be compatible with Automattic\WooCommerce\Vendor\Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::get(string $id)
FILE: /home/uarbnvd4dt71/public_html/testingsite.wordpresssite.ca/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/lib/packages/League/Container/Container.php[15]
--- TRACE ---
CLASS___: Duplicator\Installer\Utils\Tests\WP\TestsErrorHandler::shutdownFILE: [-1]`

Does anyone know the fix to this? I'm thinking it might be related to PHP as I have a difference in versions between the host and the website I am trying to migrate

I haven't gotten this error previously but I tried to look into Stack Overflow and the Duplicator FAQ but no one had a solution to this error

Comment: What versions of PHP, WordPress and WooCommerce are you running? Does this help you - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-after-upgrading-wocommerce-to-6-9-2/

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across something similar (not the same though but also Woocommerce in error reporting). Had to do with PHP settings, increasing in my case memory_limit to 512MB and solved the issue. You might also want to check max exec time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).